# Libraries of Tomcat 7.0 in conflict with httpcore-4.3.2.jar

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jar, apache-commons-httpclient, conflicting-libraries

I created dynamic web project in eclipse and want to add httpcore-4.3.2.jar lib. Every time I try to add it, Tomcat stops working. I have to use HttpClient and I can't use anything else.

How to resolve this problem?

this is the error message:

```
 Grave: Exception starting Context with name [/FitsInterface]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component              
 [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FitsInterface]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3954)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
 ....

 ....

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
... 22 more
```

Comment: Where did you put that jar?

Comment: I found a solution: you have to deploy the libraries you included in the project build path.

If you are using eclipse, then: Properties > Deployment Assembly > add libraries from build path

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: you have to deploy the libraries you included in the project build path.

If you are using eclipse, then: Properties > Deployment Assembly > add libraries from build path